# Use nodejs to fetch data and return it to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to fetch some html via nodejs and fetch the output in my browser , So I used following code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const port = 3000


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));

fetch("https://example.com/results.php")  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => obj = data)
  .then(() => 
  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(obj))

  )
```

Then I started the app using `node app`

Now When i run `localhost:3000` , this gives same output everytime, But https://example.com/results.php is dynamic results page , which returns various result on every reload.

So what i need is Everytime I open localhost:3000 , it must fetch the url again and return new result in browser window , Sorry I am completely new to nodejs , I am just trying to remake php curl from nodejs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the fetch login in the `GET` route.

Think about it logically. What you want to do is:

> When user requests the / page, fetch
>   "https://example.com/results.php" and send the result to the user.

The `/` route thus has to be available at all times, and when it gets hit you fetch the required resource. Here is how it translates:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const port = 3000;


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    fetch("https://example.com/results.php")
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then((obj) => {
        res.send(obj);
      })
})


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```